# Find value in negative range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I check if the given negative value in within a range in SQL Server? when I did a `BETWEEN` it doesn't work for negative numbers. Googling also didn't help me much. Does anyone know if there's a way out from this?

SQL Server Version: 014

```
val
-1
-0.01
-2.03
1.00003
-3.004444

select  case 
      when val between -1 and -10 then 'yes' 
      else 'no'
      end as 'value_finder'
from table;
```

Comment: From [`Between`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#result-value): "BETWEEN returns `TRUE` if the value of _test_expression_ is greater than or equal to the value of _begin_expression_ and less than or equal to the value of _end_expression_." Granted, they could be more explicit, but what values are `>= -1` _and_ `<= -10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BETWEEN` requires that the *smaller* value be first and the *larger* second.  That is true for negative numbers as well:

```
when val between -10 and -1 then 'yes'
```

Note that `-10 < -1`.